# Install SQL Server Express with C# application

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I have an application that needs to have SQL Server installed in order to work, and I need to make an installer for the application that includes the installation of SQL Server Express in case it isn't already installed in the client's computer.

I tried this having my project to have a prerequisite of installing `SQL Server 2005 Express Edition SP2` and the option `Download prerequisites from the same location as my application`, but it doesn't work, as it throws errors such as

> Error 43 The install location for prerequisites has not been set to
>   'component vendor's web site' and the file
>   'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX30\WCS_64.msp' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1'
>   can not be located on disk.

I have been searching through internet but I could never make any of the methods to work.

I run into a webpage (the only example I found) to use `EnableLaunchApplication.js` to have a checkbox to run the program after the installation of itself.

But what about an `SQL Server Express` installation?

I am using `Visual Studio 2008` with C#.

EDIT:

In my setup project, I have a PostBuildEvent

```
cscript.exe"$(ProjectDir)EnableLaunchApplication.js" "$(BuiltOuputPath)"
```

but I never got the file `EnableLaunchApplication.js` (it's not a project I made, but I have to figure out a way to fix this..).

Comment: do you want to include the setup of SQL Express in your media or to download it from the Internet at setup runtime?

Comment: @DavidePiras the first option, include it in my media

Comment: so check this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562(v=sql.90).aspx#emsqlexcustapp_topic3 if you have set the option "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application" then you just need to include the package in your CD / network share.

Comment: @DavidePiras what about the `PostBuildEvent` and the `EnableLaunchApplication.js`?

Comment: This is the reason I love SQLite :) 
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

Comment: Have you seen and read [Embedding SQL Server Express into Custom Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) ??

Comment: @marc_s yes I did, it's the same document than DavidePiras told me, but, is it possible to have something easier and faster than writing all that code?

Comment: @noloman: not that I'm aware of, no ...

Comment: @marc_s maybe it's not the same but I included a `Custom Action` to execute the SQL express installer.. but it stores it in a folder called `SqlExpress`, so the `EnableLaunchApplication.js` file doesn't find it..

Answer (score 0):

I did this in VS2005 and all things go prefect. But I have the same problem as yours.I think you did all correct just some thing.you that "I finally got to make execute the SQL Server Express installer while installing my app" but how?! Run a msi file?! Did you check for previous installed SQL server instance engine? Why you want to install your app before SQL server?!

An other question is if client already have SQL server engine it is a good property and prefect and you have not to install it.

Create a standard installation process dude.install prerequisites first and if they are be installed the install them and if already installed use them.

And the last. Install Windows installer as a prerequisite.

Try to do every thing in its common process.

Comment: my problem is that the client wants to install SQL Express without having internet, so I need to provide it somehow in the CD. If I check the `Download prerequisites from the same location as my application`, then all the prerequisites will tried to be installed from the app folder, and I don't have .NET Framework or Windows installer there..

Comment: so!!! put the them by check them in prerequisites list?is the any problem with put them there?!!

Comment: Well if I try in my computer, which has .NET 3.5 and everything, just checking SQL Server 2005.. it doesn't install anything :)

Comment: so it is common.in your system all prerequisites are installed.check them to install them on the clients.i can not understand you dude :(

Comment: so I included Sql Express as a prerequisite and when installing it, it tells me there's already an instance of SQL installed in the computer and I can't continue